# Using VBA to prevent image printing in Word .doc

Tags: vba, ms-word

I set up a resume which has an 8.5 by 11 image in the background (could set it up to be a watermark if need be).  Now i would like to get it set up so that it will not print the background image automatically so that the employer doesn't have to jump through hoops.  After looking online I noticed that this is probably something that must be set up using VBA and templates.  Any insite or anyone willing to tackle this it would be greatly appreciated.

Pretty much i just want my Word document to not print images or watermarks with out having the person who prints it set anything up.(doesn't have to be both)

Comment: Umm - I'm not going to enable macros in a resume, and if I got a resume with macros in it, I might be dis-inclined to even give it a first look.

Comment: To be clear - I'm not trying to be snarky here: anyone reviewing resumes likely has at least a dozen or so to look at, so they're not going to want to spend time trying to figure out what the macro in your resume does before they enable it...

Comment: Tim , would a person overlook a resume with a designed background because they wouldn't want to deal with printing it?(by the way i will be applying for art positions)

Comment: I'd prefer a plain background, but then I'm about as far from being involved in art as you can get...

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need VBA for this?

To disable printing of background colors and images in Word 2010, simply follow these steps

Click on File | Option

You will get a "Word Options" Dialog Box.

Under Display Tab, simply uncheck "Print BackGround Colors and Images"

Comment: Its a custom Background image created in photshop so I'm faking the background part by using an image so this wouldn't work.  And as stated the person needing to print this would have to take these steps which i dont want.

Comment: In that case send him 2 resumes. One for viewing pleasure and the other for printing. I agree with @Tim Williams that macros in Resume will certainly create a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do not know why but this semes to work just fine.

```
Public WithEvents appWord As Word.Application

Private Sub Document_Open()
    Set appWord = Application
    ' Not sure if your image is a shape or inlineshape, so...
    If ThisDocument.Shapes.Count Then
        ' First Shape is now visible
        ThisDocument.Shapes(1).Visible = msoTrue
    ElseIf ThisDocument.InlineShapes.Count Then
        ' First inlineshpae has medium brightness
        ThisDocument.InlineShapes.Item(1).PictureFormat.Brightness = 0.5
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub appWord_DocumentBeforePrint(ByVal Doc As Document, Cancel As Boolean)

 Dim intResponse As Integer

 intResponse = MsgBox("This document contains a background image. " & _
    "Would you like to hide it before printing?", vbYesNo, _
    "Hide Background Image?")
     If intResponse = vbYes Then
         hide_images

     ElseIf intResponse = vbNo Then

        show_images
     End If
End Sub

Sub hide_images()

    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    With ActiveWindow
        .DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = True
        .DisplayVerticalScrollBar = True
        .DisplayLeftScrollBar = False
        .StyleAreaWidth = CentimetersToPoints(0)
        .DisplayVerticalRuler = True
        .DisplayRightRuler = False
        .DisplayScreenTips = True
        With .View
            .ShowAnimation = True
            .Draft = False
            .WrapToWindow = False
            .ShowPicturePlaceHolders = False
            .ShowFieldCodes = False
            .ShowBookmarks = False
            .FieldShading = wdFieldShadingWhenSelected
            .ShowTabs = False
            .ShowSpaces = False
            .ShowParagraphs = False
            .ShowHyphens = False
            .ShowHiddenText = False
            .ShowAll = True
            .ShowDrawings = True
            .ShowObjectAnchors = False
            .ShowTextBoundaries = False
            .ShowHighlight = True
        End With
    End With
    With Options
        .UpdateFieldsAtPrint = False
        .UpdateLinksAtPrint = False
        .DefaultTray = "Druckereinstellungen verwenden"
        .PrintBackground = True
        .PrintProperties = False
        .PrintFieldCodes = False
        .PrintComments = False
        .PrintHiddenText = False
        .PrintDrawingObjects = False
        .PrintDraft = False
        .PrintReverse = False
        .MapPaperSize = True
    End With
    With ActiveDocument
        .PrintPostScriptOverText = False
        .PrintFormsData = False
    End With
End Sub

Sub show_images()

    With Options
        .UpdateFieldsAtPrint = False
        .UpdateLinksAtPrint = False
        .DefaultTray = "Druckereinstellungen verwenden"
        .PrintBackground = True
        .PrintProperties = False
        .PrintFieldCodes = False
        .PrintComments = False
        .PrintHiddenText = False
        .PrintDrawingObjects = True
        .PrintDraft = False
        .PrintReverse = False
        .MapPaperSize = True
    End With
    With ActiveDocument
        .PrintPostScriptOverText = False
        .PrintFormsData = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Cheers
mARTin

Answer (score 0):

I use the following (short) procedure as a ribbon extension for showing/hiding logo's in document headers so users can toggle before print/pdf creation.

```
Sub ShowHideLogoInHeader
```

local errorhandler (not critical)

```
On Local Error GoTo ErrHandler
```

dim shaperange

```
Dim myStory As ShapeRange
Set myStory = ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdFirstPageHeaderStory).ShapeRange
myStory.Visible = Not myStory.Visible

Exit Sub
```

ErrHandler:
report error (separate function) in debug

```
ReportError "modRibbon - ToonOfVerbergLogo"
Err.Clear
End Sub
```